# add circular overlay to mapview

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, cllocation, mkoverlay

I am trying to add a circular overlay in ios mapview,in view did load i added following code

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 53.809638, -1.554586 );
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:center radius:1000];
    circle.title = @"University of Leeds";
    [self.map addOverlay:circle];
```

and also included the delegate function

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]]) {
        MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:(MKCircle*)overlay];
        circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        circleView.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        circleView.lineWidth = 2;
        return circleView;
    }
```

but it's not working why?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is your `map` delegate set?
If your creating your map in Interface Builder: Check if you map is properly connected.

(Note that radius is in meters)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the method GetOverlayRenderer which should create a MKCircleRenderer. Below an example in Xamarin.

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView _nativeMapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
{
    if (overlay is MKCircle)
    {
        // Create a renderer if needed
        if (_circleRenderer == null)
        {
            _circleRenderer = new MKCircleRenderer(overlay as MKCircle);
            _circleRenderer.FillColor = UIColor.Red;
            _circleRenderer.Alpha = 0.3f;
        }
        return _circleRenderer;
    }
```